# how to show the hidden data from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<form name="form11" method="post" action="hpdata.php" enc type="multipart/form-data">
<input name="pro" id="pro" type="hidden"  value= "CMS" />
<input name="piror" id="piror" type="hidden"  value= "P1" />
<input name="stat" id="stat" type="hidden"  value= "In Progress" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="groovy button" value="...">              
</form>
```

in this code I can't see the data

Comment: you need to complete your question by showing us the code , which is retrieving this data

Comment: Incomplete question...edit it first @user302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hidden attribute just use for hide item from the UI. but still you can acsess them after form is submitted using $_POST['id here'] (if form method is get you should get it through $_GET[])

Answer (score 0):

the code you provided has nothing to do with mysql.

It is a html fragment. It contains hidden inputs. If you want to make them visible remove type="hidden".

But most likely there is a purpose why they are hidden. Often this is done to keep values for different form pages or to present the user with pretty values, but send easier to handle versions to the server. (e.g. dates can have different formats in different countrys, but its easier to just send them in a standardized form --> this one would be in a hidden input.)